# rpm -i for centos 6.6 says error: /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.nNbNhx: is not an rpm package

Tags: rpm, centos6

I need to rebuild my Centos 6.6 system. I have issued the command:

> rpm -i http://vault.centos.org/6.6/updates/Source/SPackages/
>   kernel-2.6.32-504.23.4.el6.src.rpm 2>&1 | grep -v exist

This package IS in the vault, but I get the message:

> error: /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.nNbNhx: not an rpm package (or package
>   manifest)

I have tried with earlier kernel packages and get the same error message. I am currently running Centos 2.6.32-504.cl6.s390x

Comment: The original command was copied/pasted from the Centros wiki file.The command was line-wrapped and the eol symbol was inserted when I copied & pasted. Removing the extra line (which was not visible because of the width of my terminal session) fixed the problem.